# How to validate ODataQueryOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

I'd like to reject an OData request if it has `$top` option value exceeding a global limit. `ODataQueryOptions` is created manually and I don't know how to correctly trigger its validation.

#### Assemblies affected

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="7.0.0" />
```

#### Reproduce steps

I do global setup like this:

```cs
public static void UseODataRoutes(this IRouteBuilder routeBuilder, 
    IEdmModel edmModel)
{
    routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute(RouteName,
        RoutePrefix,
        containerBuilder => containerBuilder.AddService(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, provider => edmModel));

    routeBuilder.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Select().MaxTop(1);

    routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
}
```

And manually create an `ODataQueryOptions<TEntity>` instance:

```cs
public ODataQueryFactory(IHttpContextAccessor httpAccessor, IPerRouteContainer container)
{
    _request = httpAccessor.HttpContext.Request;
    _odataServiceProvider = container.GetODataRootContainer(ODataExtentions.RouteName);
}

public ODataQueryOptions<TEntity> CreateQueryOptions<TEntity>()
    where TEntity : class
{
    var model = _odataServiceProvider.GetService<IEdmModel>();
    var path = _request.ODataFeature().Path;
    var context = new ODataQueryContext(model, typeof(TEntity), path);

    var queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions<TEntity>(context, _request);

    return queryOptions;
}
```

The problem is that the global `MaxTop` is ignored leading to successful `GET /foo?$top=10` request even if `MaxTop(1)` has been called.

However, if I just add:

```cs
queryOptions.Validate(new ODataValidationSettings()
{
    MaxTop = 1
});
```

To my factory method, then the request with `$top=10` produce a perfectly looking exception leading to `400` response. That's my goal.

How to automatically trigger this validation or automatically create an `ODataValidationSettings` instance using all the global settings previously passed to `IRouteBuilder`?

P.S. I'd like to avoid manual `ODataValidationSettings` creation and use the standard Odata API instead.

Answer (score 2):

To validate the query using only global options, pass an empty `ODataValidationSettings` parameter:

```
queryOptions.Validate(new ODataValidationSettings());
```

More info on [GitHub](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1717) (I directly asked OData developers).

P.S. I still have no idea how to set a default global limit to prevent selecting all the entities from the db if `$top` hasn't been specified. The default validation doesn't cover this case.

Comment: Use MaxTop while setting up routebuilder in startup